# android file hosting

Tags: android, packaging

I have to make an android application which have many specific graphical resource files for several resolutions.
I manage the devices in 3 categories according to their screen resolution :

- width <480px
- width between 480px and 600px
- width >600px

I don't want to include these assets  (~150MB) in my apk, and download only those required by the device. 
I read the doc about the "multiple APK support" but my categories does not fit with the screen size criteria which depends of screen dimensions.

Is there any other solution than to make my own download server ?

Comment: You might also read this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Yes I read it, but I can manage only 2 expansion file per apk. Moreover the doc says : "Most of the time, Google Play downloads and saves your expansion files at the same time it downloads the APK to the device". So it doesn't solve my problem?

Comment: But perhaps you can create 3 apk for your 3 categories, and then create 3 differents expansion pack (one pack for one apk)

Comment: I can create several apk which are related to the screen dimensions (small, normal, large, xlarge) but not to the screen resolution.

Comment: Are you sure ? (I refer to the attributeandroid:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" seen here : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Comment: dp is "density-independent pixels" and not exactly same unit as pixels.

Comment: Sure. I looked a bit more in the doc but apparently you can only do that (with multiple APK and Market Filter) : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html